# How to set popup position?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I work on Asp.Net vs08 C# .I want to show popup ** Bottom** of the button .Not on center of page.Here is my syntax .

**Aspx code:**

```
<input id="Button3" type="button" value="Open 1" />
```

**Jquery:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
      $("#Popup").dialog({
          bgiframe: true,
          autoOpen: false,
          height: 300,
          modal: true,
          buttons: {
              Cancel: function() {
                  $(this).dialog("close");
              }
          },
         close: function() {
              allFields.val("").removeClass("ui-state-error");
         }
      }).parent().appendTo($("form:first"));
      $("#Button3").click() {
        $("#Popup").dialog("open");
      });
    });
</script>
```

**show me syntax or modify my syntax**. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to add a `position` field to your options argument:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
      $("#Popup").dialog({
          bgiframe: true,
          autoOpen: false,
          height: 300,
          modal: true,
          position: [100, 200], // 100 is x location, 200 is y location, in pixels
          buttons: {
              Cancel: function() {
                  $(this).dialog("close");
              }
          },
         close: function() {
              allFields.val("").removeClass("ui-state-error");
         }
      }).parent().appendTo($("form:first"));
      $("#Button3").click() {
        $("#Popup").dialog("open");
      });
    });
</script>
```

`position` can also accept a string like `"top"` or `"left"`.

See the [jQuery UI Dialog documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Dialog#option-position) for more information about this.

Comment: Thanks .But i want to set position dynamically .How to set position of popup left of the button control,your given syntax  position: [100, 200], not solve my problem.

Comment: @user280048 rather than setting `[100,200]`, just pass in some position that you calculate...

Answer (score 0):

Just add the Position keyword to your query like

position: [400, 500]

Comment: Thanks .But i want to set position dynamically .How to set position of popup left of the button control,your given syntax  position: [100, 200], not solve my problem.